# Axiomatic Systems, Binary Operations, and Groups

Tags: group-theory, functions, binary-operations

We have the four axioms of the group (1. Closure, 2. Associativity, 3. Neutral Element, 4. Inverse Element).
Axiom 5: Supposing we have group $G$ which is the group of the functions $f,g,h,k:{1,2,3,4} \to {1,2,3,4}$.
Let function $f$ be the Identity function $(f(1)=1, f(2)=2...)$, Let function $g$ be in such way that, $g(1)=2, g(2)=1, g(3)=3, g(4)=4$ and let function $h$ be in such way that $h(1)=1, h(2)=2, h(3)=4, h(4)=3$. And let function $k$ be in such way that $k=g\circ h$.

The questions:

1. Prove that $G$ with the composition of the functions, is a model to the axioms 1,2,3,4,5.
2. Prove that the system 1,2,3,4,5 is not categorical.

I tried to solve that by myself, and to do that, I have made a table, Which didn't help me by any way, and now after 3 hours of trying to solving it, I am posting it there.
[image: Table]

Comment: Let us see your table

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Alright, Let me add it.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Added :)

Comment: I see.  I thought you made a table showing composition of functions -- that could help

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The table does actually shows the composition of the functions $g$ and $h$ which are labeled as requested in the problem $k$ .

Comment: Right, but if you're showing these four functions with composition comprise a group, it would help to show that compositions of *all* pairs of them are in the group (closure axiom)

Comment: Do you have any way I could composite it? Because if I composite $g$ on $f$ it's not the same thing like if I composite: $f$ on $g$.

Comment: Actually it's commutative -- you should check that $g(f(n))=f(g(n))$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $f$ is the identity so it commutes and $g$ commutes with $h$ but in general the composition of functions is not commutative. The symmetric group on four letters is certainly not commutative.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Right, but how should I composite the functions? Should I composite it like so: $f\circ g\circ h\circ k$ or like $g\circ f\circ k\circ h$ or in any other way? 
Or will it always be the same?

Comment: @CyclotomicField:  I agree that the symmetric group on four letters is not commutative, but OP is asking about a subgroup that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because function composition is associative, this operation is associative. The neutral element is the identify function $f$. Since all the functions are bijective, they are invertible. All that's left to check is closure.

We can interpret these functions as permutations of the numbers $1,2,3$ and $4$. Since $g$ tranposes $1$ and $2$ and $h$ transposes $3$ and $4$ these functions commute. This also shows that $g,h$ and $k$ are their own inverses.

Comment: OP said the group consists of functions $f,g,h,$ and $k$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I see it now.

Comment: Yup, Sorry to destroy your answer :( .

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko that's ok I fixed it for you.

Comment: Until there I understood everything, In order to prove the closure, Can I say that the functions are closed because they transpose elements which are already in the group, Which makes it closed?

Comment: They transpose elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, but since the elements transposed are disjoint, it's commutative

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko careful, they don't transpose elements of the group, they transpose elements in the set. I find it useful to think of the numbers as the nouns and the functions are the verbs to keep the set and the action separated in my mind. The key feature is that transposing twice will simply undo what was done, and that $g$ and $h$ never transpose the same elements.

Comment: Okay, and one last question, How do I prove that this axiomatic system (1,2,3,4,5) is not categorical?

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko I haven't heard of a categorical group before. What's the definition you're using?

Comment: Hey, I am not talking about the group in that case.
In this case I am talking about the axiomatic system, as stated in my question.

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko Ok, I still need the definition to answer the question.

Comment: Okay, So basically we have a model to this axiomatic system (The one we used in this case), and we need another model to this axiomatic system which is different and not injective.

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko I can certainly concoct a different axiomatic system but I've also never heard of an injective axiomatic system. What does that mean?

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko are you looking for some function $\varphi :G \rightarrow G$ that preserves the group structure but is not injective? Consider $\varphi(f)=f, \varphi(x)=g$ for $x \neq f$.

Comment: Basically, Let's say you've got an axiom: "There most be 4 points" and you've got a  model with the points: 1,2,3,4 and the lines {1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,4},{2,3}, and to write a model formally, You write: M={1,2,3,4,{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,4},{2,3}}.
And you've got a different model which does the same axioms, that is the points are: 1,2,3,4 and the lines are: {1,2,3,4} and the model is: N={1,2,3,4,{1,2,3,4}}.
So basically it is the doing the same axiom, but the lines are different, and the models are different and not injective ($M$ is not injective in $N$)

Comment: Sorry for the difficulty in reading this, but the MathJax thing in this forum is dumb and is removing the curled parenthesis when you write lots of them.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Not exactly.

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko how do you get the lines from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ in $N$? Shouldn't lines be defined by two points or are they all colinear or?

Comment: They can be colinear, they can be defined by two points only, they can be defined by six points and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Cayley table for your group:

$o\;f\;g\;h\;k$

$f\;f\;g\;h\;k$

$g\;g\;f\;k\;h$

$h\;h\;k\;f\;g$

$k\;k\;h\;g\;f$

In fact, it is isomorphic to the [Klein vierergruppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).

Comment: Okay, and how can I implement it in there, and say that it's closed, associative, that it has neutral element, that it has inverse element?

Comment: If you verify the table, you'll see it's closed, it has neutral element ($f$), and each element is its own inverse; associative property would be more tedious this way, but, as @CyclotomicField noted, function composition is always associative

Comment: Yup, but since function composition is associative, then it should also be associative in fact.

Comment: Okay, and one last question, How do I prove that this axiomatic system (1,2,3,4,5) is not categorical?